# How could I modify my awk script in order to print the correct values for matches using a text file as input?

Tags: awk

I have some text files that contain the output of a readers-writers lock in the format of “sr” and “dr”, which are short for “start read” and “done read” and "sw" and "dw" which are short for "start write" and "done write".

Basically, I am trying to keep counts of the number of current readers and the number of current writers.  For example, the number of current writers will increase on a ‘sw’ line and decrease on a ‘dw’ line.

For example my first text file contains the following:

```
sr
sw
dw
dr
```

So, the output for that should be:

```
$ awk -f check-rwlock.awk test1.txt
maxr = 1, maxw = 1
reader/writer test: FAIL    
writer/writer test: PASS
```

Because there was a overlapping between the reader and writer operations the test "FAILED" whereas there was no overlapping between the writer operations so the test "PASSED".

---

This is the `awk` script I have written:

```
/sr/{
    read_count++
}
/sw/{
    write_count++
}
END{
    print "maxr = " read_count", " "maxw = " write_count
}
```

How could I further modify my script in order to get the output that I want with the tests for reader/writer and writer/writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
/^sr/ {
    cr++
    mxr = cr>mxr ? cr : mxr
} 
/^sw/ {
    cw++
    mxw = cw>mxw ? cw : mxw
} 
/^dr/ { cr-- } 
/^dw/ { cw-- }
cr && cw { rwf=1 }
cw>1 { wwf=1 }
END {
    print "maxr = " mxr ", maxw = " mxw
    print "reader/writer test: " (rwf ? "FAIL" : "PASS")
    print "writer/writer test: " (wwf ? "FAIL" : "PASS")
}
```

Example input:

```
sr
dr
sw
dw
sr
sw
sw
dr
dw
dw
```

Example output:

```
maxr = 1, maxw = 2
reader/writer test: FAIL
writer/writer test: FAIL
```

Note that your script does not count maximum concurrent operations, it just counts all started operations. So the result will be incorrect for my input.